# How do I store binary .wav data in a file?

Tags: numpy, file, wav

I'm trying to get .wav data stored in a txt-file in C array format to copy into a C program. This is done in a jupyter notebook running locally. The file has 16kHz and int16 PCM format.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import numpy

a = read("sound.wav")
numpy.array(a[1])
fd = open("wav_array.txt", 'w')
numpy.ndarray.tofile(fd, ', ')
```

This causes an error:

```
C:\Users\JDA1E~1.TSC\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15916/363132415.py:4: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  a = read("sound.wav")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JDA1E~1.TSC\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15916/363132415.py in <module>
      5 numpy.array(a[1])
      6 fd = open("wav_array.txt", 'w')
----> 7 numpy.ndarray.tofile(fd, ', ')

TypeError: descriptor 'tofile' for 'numpy.ndarray' objects doesn't apply to a '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

How can I get the contents from a .wav file as binary/hex values into a readable file? (Quick and dirty solutions are ok as well)

Comment: Doesn't `'rb'` mean you open the file for reading?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> numpy.array(a[1])
> fd = open("wav_array.txt", 'w')
> numpy.ndarray.tofile(fd, ', ')
> ```

Rather than discarding the `numpy.array` and calling a static method, you meant:

```
with open("wav_array.txt", 'w') as fd: numpy.array(a[1]).tofile(fd, ', ')
```